# should I delete or disable documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a sql background and know that deletes are a pain in the ass but in mongo they dont seem too bad.  Does mongo handle deletes efficiently or should I mark the doc as disabled instead?

Comment: Not sure SO is the right place for this kind of question since this is preference.  You should make this decision based on your systems needs and not on "how easy is it going to be". I personally like soft deletes and then move old data to a data warehouse or purge it after a set amount of time if it's not critical to keep around.